# Bloc Consumer is not listening to states

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

when i press the add or minus button the number doesn't change and the bloc consumer doesn't listen to states i don't know the reason i tried every thing but nothing worked with me i want to know how to listen to changes and make the number change when i press the buttons add or minus

`

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  ColorsCubit cubit = ColorsCubit();
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => ColorsCubit(),
        child: BlocConsumer<ColorsCubit, ColorsStates>(
          listener: (context,ColorsStates state) {
            if (state is InitialState) print("in initial state");
            if(state is AddState)print('add state');
          },
          builder: (context,ColorsStates state) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(onPressed: ()=>cubit.add(), child: Text("add")),
                    Text(cubit.count.toString()),
                    TextButton(onPressed: ()=>cubit.minus(), child: Text("minus")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}

// this is cubit class


class ColorsCubit extends Cubit<ColorsStates>{
  ColorsCubit() : super(InitialState());

  static ColorsCubit get(context)=>BlocProvider.of(context);

  int count=0;

  void add(){
    count++;
    emit(AddState());
  }

  void minus(){
    count++;
    emit(MinusState());
 }

}

// this is states class


abstract class ColorsStates{}

class InitialState extends ColorsStates{}

class AddState extends ColorsStates{}

class MinusState extends ColorsStates{}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

This `ColorsCubit cubit = ColorsCubit();` is different from the cubit instance you're listening to.

You could do this:

- ColorsCubit? cubit;
- Then inside the BlocConsumer method assign your cubit
- And finally, call the methods you want.

Your code would look like this now:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  ColorsCubit? cubit;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => ColorsCubit(),
        child: BlocConsumer<ColorsCubit, ColorsStates>(
          listener: (context,ColorsStates state) {
            if (state is InitialState) print("in initial state");
            if(state is AddState)print('add state');
          },
          builder: (context,ColorsStates state) {

cubit??= context.read<ColorsCubit>(); // assign cubit if it's not already assigned

            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(onPressed: ()=>cubit.add(), child: Text("add")),
                    Text(cubit.count.toString()),
                    TextButton(onPressed: ()=>cubit.minus(), child: Text("minus")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

You could also consider this approach:
Instead of using BlocProvider, use BlocProvider.value, and put your cubit as the value. This way you don't need to do what I did in the above code

Comment: but if i need to call a method from the ColorBloc in the initState how can i call it

Comment: Create the BlocProvider outside of that widget (e.g, when you return the widget just wrap it with BlocProvider), then in initState of your widget you can do `context.read<YourCubit>().yourMethod();`

Comment: I would create the instance as a member of the state, as you did in your question, and then use the BlocProvider.value constructor. This will use the existing instance of creating a new instance.

Comment: but the initState is called before building the widget

Comment: @mohamedalaa did you try the solution I posted?

Comment: yes thank you i tried your solution and it worked for me but i found another problem and solved it by assigning the Bloc Provider above the material thank you so much

Comment: Glad it helped. please consider marking the answer